# I need some recomendations about ros

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys.!
I newbie ros I'm learning C++ and I'm want to learn more about ros
I want to read a manual that really teach me how to use Ros
how friendly is ros with newbie user ?
do I need to have a master's degree in engineering to use ros ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/119286/i-need-some-recomendations-about-ros/) by [ros-friend](https://answers.ros.org/users/10976/ros-friend/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-01-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

for starting ros you can use this [Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials)

no you don't need a master's degree in engineering to use ros.just you need to know programming

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2014-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are also some books about ROS.
See http://wiki.ros.org/Books

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-01-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This book is very helpful for beginners  [www.cse.sc.edu/~jokane/agitr/](http://www.cse.sc.edu/%7Ejokane/agitr/)

---

Originally posted by [miloup](https://answers.ros.org/users/13906/miloup/) with karma: 31 on 2014-03-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1